# SVN Client integrated with OS X's Finder

Tags: macos, smartsvn

Is there a TortoiseSVN equivalent for OS X? I'm looking for an SVN client that will integrate with OS X's Finder and be added as Context menu items.

Update: Just found [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/). Anyone with feedback on it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [SCPlugin](http://scplugin.tigris.org/) which is the closest match to TortoiseSVN on OS X. It adds overlay icons as well as context menu entries to the Finder.

Comment: Is this plugin compatible with OS X 10.10 (yosemite) ?

Answer (score 10):

Note, that neither SCPlugin nor the [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) Finder integration will work on OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard), because Apple has dropped the support for Finder plugins.

Comment: Note that Dropbox does work on Snow Leopard, integrated with Finder, both in context menu and modifying icons.

Comment: I've taken a look at Dropbox and it looks like it does NOT show a context menu or own icons in the regular Finder views, but only in its own one.

Comment: On Yosemite I use XtraFinder. Looks like Yosemite does have Finder plugin support via FinderSync: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_10.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, but I've recently started using Cornerstone as a SVN client on the Mac and I'm super-happy with it.

It's about $60 and has a 30 day trial. Also try "Versions". I trailed it for a few weeks and it was the "best other" SVN client, but not as good as Cornerstone (IMO).

Comment: Cornerstone:
http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/

Nice review on the topic: 
http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2008/08/06/svn-smackdown-cornerstone-v-versions/

Answer (score 1):

Google found this:

http://scplugin.tigris.org/

doesn't seem to be as slick as tortoise, but at least it's a start.

I tried Versions for a little while, but it often got confused and irritated me quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [Versions](http://www.versionsapp.com/). Not exactly what you're looking for but close

Answer (score 1):

Agreed. SCPlugin is the best option out there. But it's a bit buggy in the latest release of OS X. Has been for a little while. Another alternative is [PathFinder](http://www.cocoatech.com/) which is a very slick Finder replacement, that has SCPlugin integrated, as well as a console, and various other SVN integrations. It's a commercial product, but well worth the money.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion svn-finder scripts are the best solution for leopard or snowleopard becauce scplugin will not work with Finder in those systems. You can download scripts from: http://svn-finder.sourceforge.net/ I also found easySVN http://sourceforge.net/projects/easy-svn/ which is not so bad and free.